# Motordoping in film The Program

Tags: doping

In the film *The Program*, about the career of Lance Armstrong, there is a scene (at about 29:45 minutes) where his mechanic turns around something on his bike and afterwards he climbs up the hills like no one else.

So I have 2 question:

1. Did Lance Armstrong cheat to win his first Tour de France using some kind of motor?
2. Was it even possible in 1999 to hide such an effective motor in a bike frame?

Comment: I'm assuming the mechanic was adjusting somethign on the bike while leaning out of a moving vehicle.  This "magic spanner"  could alllow enough recovery for an attack as the mechanic/car combination is to a siginifcant extent pushing the cyclist along.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm torn here between attempting to answer this question, and voting to close it on the grounds that you'll only ever get an opinion-based answer. But, to give the benefit of the doubt....

For the first part of your question, I'd say it was unlikely, but your pertinent words are "using a motor". He may well have cheated using other means, in  particular the blood doping for which he is now infamous.

This is largely because I think the answer to the second part of your qurstion is "no". I think that in 1999, battery technology was sufficiently primitive that it would have been impossible to conceal a motor, or that a motor that was concealable would deliver such negligible power as to be ineffective when it comes to increasing your speed. I mean, this is arguable even with 2016 technology - have a look at the size of a bettery on one of today's e-bikes, and you'll see why I say this.

I think you only have to look at mobile (cell) phones of the day to convince yourself of the limits of the technology. My gut feel is that any film you watched which showed motors was using lots of artistic license - if it contained a pile of syringes, I'd be a lot more convinced.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you are right, most answers may be opinion based. I haven't realized when posting this question. But I also thought that this is a really fascinating question, so I posted it.

Comment: this is no longer "arguable": Cancellara and Contador, at least, have been accused to use e-bikes, and an e-bike was actually detected during 2016 cyclo-cross world championship. cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_doping#Sanctioned_athletes

Comment: @OblTobl yeah, It's a difficult one. I have tried to argue my answer  in terms of the technology that was around back then, which obviously is "real" as far as I can remember. But to use that in the context of Lance's doping..... it's just my opinion.

Comment: Some modern figures: The best Li primary cells can hold 700Wh/kg.  Top cyclists can sustain 400W for period of an hour.  So just over 0.5kg is an hour's worth of pro effort.  But a motor at this power output would be rather large.  Instead a small sustained boost to the rider's power output would open up tactical opportunities.

Comment: @njzk2 to clarify, I mean that it is arguable that electricity could produce a worthwhile power boost, and that the rider could conceal it. Clearly, if someone got caught, they were unable to conceal the motor. I guess we'll only ever know when one of today's riders, after their career is over, says "I did that for years." just like with EPO

Comment: @PeteH good point on the cyclist not being able to conceal it.

Comment: @PeteH seat tube/bottom bracket motors are openly sold. Concealing the battery and controls may be more of an issue

Comment: Mobile phones from 1999 used lithium-ion batteries; the batteries were so much larger than today's because the phones demanded much more power. The battery technology was available in 1999.

Comment: @rclocher3 if you feel that my attempt to help is wrong, then by all means downvote it. I really won't be offended - as I say above, it is really just my opinion on what probably happened at the time, based on what I remember, so I could easily be wrong. If you're feeling particularly generous, you could try and help the community out by providing an answer of your own.